# How to fix mysql runtime Error

Tags: mysql

i am using mysql, when executing the store procedure it is giving runtime error .. 
 if i run query only it is executing.

```
   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE   
      `sp_get_Ad_Img_Details_dummy1`(IN `xp_postId` VARCHAR(5))
   BEGIN

    select * FROM post_ad_list post_ad_list_al 
    INNER JOIN product_images product_images_al ON 
    product_images_al.pi_postid = post_ad_list_al.p_postId WHERE   
    p_postId=xp_postId;
    END



      call sp_get_Ad_Img_Details_dummy1('20170219074922');
```

After Executing the stored procedure i am getting Erro..

How to fix it ...

```
   Error
   Static analysis:

   1 errors were found during analysis.

   Unrecognized keyword. (near "ON" at position 25)
   SQL query: Edit Edit

   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

   MySQL said: Documentation

   #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

   Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you wrote `product_images_al.pi_postid` and `Id` schould be written with a large `i` as you did it on the other words?

If you want to check Exceptions maybe try that:

```
BEGIN TRY
/* Coding ... */
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
/* Catching code... */
END CATCH
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

make sure to set foreign key check using following approach

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

or

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```